# Columns in a primary key on a datatable being re-ordered automatically?

Tags: c#, datatable, primary-key

I have a table named Permissions which is defined in a dataset named _permissionsSet and it has 3 columns:  PermissionGroup, Permission, PermissionLevel (in that order)

I set the primary key on the table to include all 3 columns like this

```
DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[3];
keys[0] = _permissionsSet.Permissions.Columns[0];
keys[1] = _permissionsSet.Permissions.Columns[1];
keys[2] = _permissionsSet.Permissions.Columns[2];

_permissionsSet.Permissions.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

When I look at the values in "keys" they are as expected:

```
? keys
{System.Data.DataColumn[3]}
[0]: {PermissionGroup}
[1]: {Permission}
[2]: {PermissionLevel}
```

But when I look at the primary key the order has changed!

```
? _permissionsSet.Permissions.PrimaryKey
{System.Data.DataColumn[3]}
[0]: {PermissionGroup}
[1]: {PermissionLevel}
[2]: {Permission}
```

This has obvious implications when using the Rows.find method in my datatable.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable.PrimaryKey property returns a simple unsorted array of DataColumn objects. If you want to sort them, take a look at [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x.aspx).  You'll need to implement an IComparer for the DataColumn type that compares instances by their .Ordinal property.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but I'm not sure that the fact that the "DataTable.PrimaryKey property returns a simple unsorted array of DataColumn objects" is that relevant.  I want the first item in my keys array to be the first column in the primary key, the second item to be the second etc.

Comment: Whe I try to use the Rows.find method the parameters that I have to pass in have to be in the same order as they are displaying in the Permissions.PrimaryKey property.  This doesn't seem right considering I set the PrimaryKey property to an array with the items in the order that I want them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the constraints collection on your data table. If there's already a unique constraint on those three columns, when you set the PrimaryKey property, the DataTable will reuse that (since logically, the order of columns in a Primary Key, as elsewhere in relational data, is meant to be irrelevant).

If you have no control over that other constraint existing, you'll need to read the Primary Key property after setting it, and re-order your Find arguments appropriately.

**Edit**

Ideally, someone would write an extension method which would look like find, but take Name/Value pairs, and work out the correct order based on the current value of the PrimaryKey property. There again, it brings up the question of whether searching in the database would be more appropriate.